# Pointer arithmetic in assembly weird behaviour (nasm)

Tags: pointers, assembly, nasm

my data segment looks like this:

```
segment data use32 class=data
    v db 4
    v1 db 4
    v2 db 4 
    v3 db 7
```

why is  `mov bh, v` a syntax error, but `mov bh, v + v1` or `mov bh, v + v1 + v2` not? v + v1, the addition of 2 pointer, is not valid pointer arithmetic, as a matter of fact. More, the debugger tells that into bh is moved a little number, like 6, but taking into consideration that the addresses are very large numbers, it seems that the nasm does some subtraction behind the scenes

I use nasm 1.6

Comment: I don't know if this is having any effect, but try removing the commas at the end of the lines for v1 and v2. I don't know nasm that well, but do you need to declare the memory model as "flat"  ?

Comment: In NASM `mov bh,v` is trying to put `v` symbol (memory address) into `bh` register, and memory address in 32b mode are 32b "wide", so that value will not fit into `bh` (8 bit register). In MASM/TASM that line would compile as `mov bh,BYTE PTR [v]`, loading value from memory, but in NASM the square brackets are mandatory, if you want value, i.e. `mov bh,[v]` (to explicitly tell assembler about memory argument size the syntax in NASM is `movzx ebx, byte [v]` to convert byte->dword. ... Other variants like `mov bh, v + v1` will add memory addresses together, and truncate result to 8 bit value.

Comment: oh, you are actually aware you are loading memory address into `bh`, and not value in memory... so you missed the point about x86 registers, how they are sized/aliased. Check for example this tutorial for basics: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html (it's MASM syntax, but NASM is quite similar) `bh` is only 8 bit register, so when the bit pattern is interpreted as unsigned integer, only values 0..255 are available.

Comment: And I tried your source with NASM 2.13.02 and `mov bh,v` does assemble fine (I mean it shows warnings about truncating the value, but does produce expected machine code loading bottom 8 bits of `v` address into `bh`). Also it doesn't like the `data` segment definition... Are you actually using NASM? Seems more like TASM/MASM syntax.

Comment: the syntax error for mov bh, v is indded "OBJ format can only handle 16- or 32-byte relocations", but mov bh, v + v1 for example moves 11 into bh

Comment: If you want to add the values together you'd have to do something like    `mov bh, [v]`
    `add bh, [v1]`
    `add bh, [v2]` . You need the square brackets to dereference the values at a label. In MASM you can leave them off, but in NASM you can't. In NASM `mov bh, v` is the MASM equivalent of `mov bh, offset v` .This is a problem since in 16-bit code the pointers are 16-bit but _BH_ is only an 8 bit register.

Comment: My interest is in valid syntax, not its logical meaning. At a bottom line, why would nasm move the sum of 2 addresses into bh (or whatever it does by mov bh, v + v1), but not one?

Comment: What would be a valid reason to load a (much too large) address into a register? There are good reasons to calculate a value based on the addresses and store that in a register. Subtracting the smaller from the bigger one for instance gives the size of the data between the two labels and that's a good value to store into CX for a counting loop for instance.

Answer (score 1):

> NASM is capable of doing algebra on these effective addresses, so that things which don't necessarily look legal are perfectly all right.

I like the way NASM treats all labels as addresses, but its address algebra certainly lacks consistency and can cause confusions.

With your example,

```
segment data use32 class=data
v       db      4    ; relative address = 0
v1      db      4    ; relative address = 1
v2      db      4    ; relative address = 2
v3      db      7    ; relative address = 3
```

The following operation

```
        mov     bx, v
```

will move the relocated address (not 0) to `bx`.

```
        mov     bh, v
```

will causes error: `OBJ format can only handle 16- or 32-byte relocations` because `bh` is 8-bit and relocation won't work.

```
        mov     bh, [v]
```

this is the correct way to load the value in `v` to `bh`.

Nasm also allows algebra on addresses, like

```
        mov     bh, [v + v1 - v2]     ; 1 + 1 - 1 = 1
        mov     bh, [v * 2 - v1]      ; 2 - 1 = 1
        mov     bh, [v * 3 - v1 * 2]  ; 3 - 2 = 1
```

The total number of labels must be 1 (or 0, see below). So it doesn't allow codes like these

```
        mov     bh, [v + v1]          ; 1 + 1 = 2
        mov     bh, [v - v1 * 2]      ; 1 - 2 = -1
        mov     bh, [v * 3 - v1]      ; 3 - 1 = 2
```

due to `invalid effective address: impossible segment base multiplier` or `relative call to absolute address not supported by OBJ format`.

Strangely, it allows these

```
        mov     bh, [v - v1]          ; 1 - 1 = 0
        mov     bh, [v * 3 - v1 * 3]  ; 3 - 3 = 0
```

The generated codes use absolute address. I expect NASM to give a warning but it doesn't. To me it as a bug.

Finally, NASM also allows algebra on addresses without `[]`, with NO restriction

```
        mov     bh, v - v1            ; same as mov bh, 0-1
        mov     bh, v + v1            ; same as mov bh, 0+1
        mov     bh, v + v1 * 2 + v3   ; same as mov bh, 0+1*2+3
```

The first one certainly makes sense. The others can be useful when combined with others:

```
        mov     eax, v2 + v3
        sub     eax, v + v1
```

To summarize, when using `v` by itself (`mov ebx, v`), NASM uses relocated address. When doing address algebra (`mov ebx, v+v1-v2`), NASM uses relative addresses. So, yes it is a bit confusing.